# Theorem, big Paralist and Amsart

Tags: amsthm, amsart, paralist

I'd like to enunciate a theorem with a large list of graphs (tikzcd) side by side. You can see that Tex skips a large space in the theorem and still does not show the whole list.

I think the problem is the amsart package which is a magazine requirement.

[image: Example]

Sorry about the very large file.

Thank you in advance.

```
\documentclass[10pt,reqno]{amsart}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=176mm, paperheight=250mm, textheight=189mm, tmargin=35mm, lmargin=30mm, rmargin=20mm, headsep=8mm, headheight=11.0pt, footskip=30pt, twoside=true}

\usepackage[fixlanguage]{babelbib}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tensor} 
\usepackage{amsmath} % operatorname
\usepackage{amsfonts} % mathhbb
\usepackage{amssymb} % widetilde ncong
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{paralist} %listagem
\usepackage{tabto}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\rvdots}{%
    \vbox{
        \baselineskip4\p@\lineskiplimit\z@
        \kern-\p@
        \hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}
    }}

\usepackage{MnSymbol} % udots

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}


\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Let $K\Delta \cong KQ/I$ be a PHI algebra of type $\mathbb{E}_7$ such that $\overline{Q}$ is not of tree type. Then $K\Delta$ or $K\Delta^{op}$ is isomorphic to one of the following algebras:

\NumTabs{2}
\begin{inparaenum}

\noindent %1
\item
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
                                            & \bullet \arrow[dl]    &                   & \bullet  \arrow[ll]   &\\
\bullet \arrow[rrrr, dotted, dash]  &                           &                   &                           & \bullet \arrow[ul] \arrow[dd] \\
                                &                   &                   &                   &\\
\bullet \arrow[uu]                  &                   & \bullet \arrow[ll]    &                   & \bullet \arrow[ll]
\end{tikzcd}
\tab\item %2
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
&&\bullet \arrow[dl] &&\\
\bullet &\bullet \arrow[l] \ar[rr, dotted, dash] &&\bullet \arrow[dd] \arrow[ul] &\\
&&&&\\
&\bullet \arrow[uu] &\bullet \arrow[l] &\bullet \arrow[l] & 
\end{tikzcd}
\tab\item %3
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
&&&\bullet \arrow[dll] &&\\
\bullet \ar[d] &\bullet \ar[l] \arrow[rrrr, dotted, dash]  &&&&\bullet \arrow[ull] \arrow[ddl] \\
\bullet &&&&&\\
&&\bullet \arrow[uul] &&\bullet \arrow[ll] & 
\end{tikzcd}
\tab\item %4
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
&&\bullet \arrow[dll] && \\
\bullet \ar[dd] \arrow[rrrr, dotted, dash] &&&&\bullet \arrow[ull] \arrow[ddl] \\
&&&& \\
\bullet &\bullet \arrow[uul] &&\bullet \arrow[ll] & \bullet \ar[uu]
\end{tikzcd}
\tab\item %5
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
                &                   &                                                   & \bullet           &\\
\bullet \arrow[dd]  &                   & \bullet \arrow[ll] \arrow[rr] \arrow[dd, dotted, dash]    &                           & \bullet \arrow[ul] \arrow[dd] \\
                &                   &                                                   &                   &\\
\bullet \arrow[rr]  &                   & \bullet                                           &                   & \bullet \arrow[ll]
\end{tikzcd}
\tab\item %6
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
                &                   &                               & \bullet \arrow[ld]    &\\
\bullet \arrow[dd]  &                   & \bullet \arrow[rr, dotted, dash]  &                           & \bullet \arrow[ul] \arrow[dd] \\
                &                   &                               &                   &\\
\bullet \arrow[rr]  &                   & \bullet \arrow[uu]                &                   & \bullet \arrow[ll]
\end{tikzcd}
\tab\item %7
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
\bullet \arrow[dr]  &                   & \bullet \arrow[ll] \arrow[ld, dotted, dash] \arrow[rd]    &                           & \bullet \\
                & \bullet           &                                                   & \bullet \arrow[dd] \arrow[ur] &       \\
                &                   &                                                   &                           &       \\
                & \bullet \arrow[uu]    &                                                   & \bullet \arrow[ll]            & 
\end{tikzcd}
\tab\item %8
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
%               &                           &                   &                                                   &                           \\
\bullet             & \bullet \arrow[d] \arrow[rr] \arrow[ddrr, dotted, dash]   & &\bullet \arrow[dd]   \\
                & \bullet \arrow[d]                                 & &                     \\
\bullet \arrow[uu]  & \bullet \arrow[l] \arrow[rr]                          & & \bullet
\end{tikzcd}
\tab\item %9
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
\bullet \arrow[r] &\bullet \arrow[dd, dotted, dash] &&\bullet \arrow[dd] \\
&&& \\
\bullet \arrow[uu] &\bullet \arrow[l] \arrow[rr] &&\bullet \ar[uull]\\
&\bullet \ar[u] &&
\end{tikzcd}
\tab\item %10
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
&&\bullet \arrow[dr] &\\
\bullet \arrow[r] &\bullet \arrow[dd, dotted, dash] &&\bullet \arrow[dd]    \\
&&&\\
\bullet \ar[r] &\bullet \arrow[luu] \arrow[rr] &&\bullet \arrow[uull]
\end{tikzcd}
\tab\item %11
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
                &                                                   & \bullet \arrow[dr]    &                   \\
\bullet             & \bullet \arrow[d] \arrow[ddrr, dotted, dash] \arrow[ur]   &                   & \bullet \arrow[dd]    \\
                & \bullet \arrow[d]                                 &                   &                   \\
                & \bullet \arrow[luu] \arrow[rr]                            &                   & \bullet   
\end{tikzcd}
\tab\item %12
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
\bullet \arrow[dd] &&\bullet \arrow[ll] \arrow[ddr] &\bullet \\
&&& \\
\bullet \ar[d] \arrow[urur, dotted, dash] &&&\bullet \arrow[dl] \arrow[uu]  \\
\bullet &&\bullet \arrow[ull] & 
\end{tikzcd}
\tab\item %13
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
\bullet \arrow[dd]  &                   & \bullet \arrow[ddr, dotted, dash]     & \bullet \arrow[l]         \\
                & \bullet \arrow[ur]    &                               &                           \\
\bullet \arrow[ur]  &                   &                               & \bullet \arrow[dl] \arrow[uu] \\
                &                   & \bullet \arrow[ull]               & 
\end{tikzcd}
\tab\item %14
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
\bullet \arrow[rr] &&\bullet \arrow[ddd, dotted, dash] &&&\bullet \arrow[dddl] \\
&&&&& \\
&&&&& \\
\bullet \ar[r] &\bullet \ar[r] &\bullet \arrow[lluuu] \arrow[rr] &&\bullet \arrow[uuull] & 
\end{tikzcd}
\tab\item %15
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
\bullet     && \bullet \arrow[d] \arrow[rrr]    &&                                  & \bullet \arrow[dddl]  \\
        && \bullet \arrow[d]                &&                                  &                   \\
        && \bullet \arrow[d]                &&                                  &                   \\
        && \bullet \arrow[lluuu] \arrow[rr] && \bullet \arrow[uuull, dotted, dash]  & 
\end{tikzcd}
\tab\item %16
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
                    &&                                                  & & \bullet                         \\
\bullet \arrow[drr] && \bullet \arrow[ll] \arrow[drr] \arrow[d, dotted, dash]   & & \bullet \arrow[u]               \\
\bullet \arrow[u]       && \bullet                                          & & \bullet \arrow[ll] \arrow[u]
\end{tikzcd}
\tab\item %17
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
\bullet \arrow[dd]   \arrow[rrr]    &                   &                           & \bullet \arrow[ddl, dotted, dash] & \bullet \arrow[dd]    \\
                            & \bullet \arrow[ul]    &                           &                               &                   \\
\bullet                     &                   & \bullet \arrow[ul] \arrow[rr] &                               & \bullet \arrow[uul]
\end{tikzcd}
\tab\item %18
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
&\bullet \arrow[ddl] &&\bullet \ar[ll] \\
&&&\\
\bullet \arrow[rr, dotted, dash] && \bullet \ar[uul] \arrow[d] &\bullet \ar[uu] \ar[l] \arrow[uull, dotted, dash] \\
\bullet \arrow[u] &&\bullet \arrow[ll] &
\end{tikzcd}
\tab\item  %19
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
\bullet &\bullet \arrow[ddl] &&\bullet \arrow[ll] & \\
&&&&\\
\bullet \ar[uu] \arrow[rrrr, dotted, dash] &&&&\bullet \arrow[d] \arrow[uulll]  \\
\bullet \arrow[u] &&&&\bullet \arrow[llll]
\end{tikzcd}
\tab\item %20
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
&&\bullet \arrow[rr] &&\bullet \arrow[ddll, dotted, dash] \\
&&&&\\
\bullet \arrow[rr] &&\bullet \arrow[rr] \arrow[uu] &&\bullet \arrow[d] \arrow[uu] \\
\bullet &&&&\bullet \arrow[llll]
\end{tikzcd}
\tab\item %21
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
&\bullet \arrow[dddl] &&&\bullet \ar[lll] \\
&&&&\\
&&&&\\
\bullet \arrow[rr, dotted, dash] &&\bullet \arrow[dl] \arrow[uuul] &\bullet \ar[l] &\bullet \ar[uuulll, dotted, dash] \ar[uuu] \ar[l] \\
&\bullet \arrow[ul] &&&
\end{tikzcd}
\tab\item  %22
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
&&\bullet \arrow[dddll] &&\bullet \arrow[ll] \\
\bullet &&&&\bullet \ar[dd] \\
&&&&\\
\bullet \arrow[rrrr, dotted, dash] \ar[uu] &&&&\bullet \arrow[dll] \arrow[uuull] \\
&&\bullet \arrow[ull] && 
\end{tikzcd}
\tab\item %23
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
&\bullet \arrow[rrr] &&&\bullet \\
&&&&\\
&&&&\\
\bullet \arrow[r] &\bullet \arrow[rr] \ar[uuu] \arrow[uuurrr, dotted, dash] &&\bullet \arrow[r] &\bullet \arrow[d] \arrow[uuu]  \\
&&&& \bullet 
\end{tikzcd}
\tab\item %24
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
&\bullet \arrow[dddr] \arrow[dddrr, dotted, dash] \arrow[rr] &&\bullet \arrow[ddd] &\\
&&&&\\
&&&&\\
\bullet \arrow[dr] \ar[uuur] \arrow[rr, dotted, dash] &&\bullet \arrow[r] &\bullet \arrow[r] &\bullet \\
&\bullet \arrow[ur] &&&
\end{tikzcd}
\tab\item  %25
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
&\bullet \arrow[dddr] \arrow[dddrr, dotted, dash] \arrow[rr] &&\bullet \arrow[ddd] &\\
&&&&\\
&&&&\\
\bullet \arrow[dr] \ar[uuur] \arrow[rr, dotted, dash] &&\bullet \arrow[r] &\bullet &\\
\bullet \arrow[u] &\bullet \arrow[ur] &&&
\end{tikzcd}
\end{inparaenum}
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What you have here is, in essence, a very large graphic, and it simply doesn't fit in the space available on the page.  You should find a way to break it into several pieces, so that it can go onto more than one page.  (Sorry I can't help with that; I don't have a working tex system available just now.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that `inparaenum` makes a single unbreakable box with the material inside it. I suggest using the `tasks` package.

This requires using `ampersand replacement=\&`, but it's just one “find and replace”.

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,reqno]{amsart}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  paperwidth=176mm,
  paperheight=250mm,
  textheight=189mm,
  tmargin=35mm,
  lmargin=30mm,
  rmargin=20mm,
  headsep=8mm,
  headheight=11.0pt,
  footskip=30pt,
  twoside=true,
}

\usepackage[fixlanguage]{babelbib}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tensor} 
\usepackage{amsmath} % operatorname
\usepackage{amsfonts} % mathhbb
\usepackage{amssymb} % widetilde ncong
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{tasks}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\rvdots}{%
    \vbox{
        \baselineskip4\p@\lineskiplimit\z@
        \kern-\p@
        \hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}
    }}

%\usepackage{MnSymbol} % udots


\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Let $K\Delta \cong KQ/I$ be a PHI algebra of type $\mathbb{E}_7$ 
such that $\overline{Q}$ is not of tree type. Then $K\Delta$ or 
$K\Delta^{op}$ is isomorphic to one of the following algebras:
\tikzcdset{ampersand replacement=\&}%
\begin{tasks}[counter-format=(tsk[1]),label-format=\upshape,label-width=2em](2)
\task
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
                                            \& \bullet \arrow[dl]    \&                   \& \bullet  \arrow[ll]   \&\\
\bullet \arrow[rrrr, dotted, dash]  \&                           \&                   \&                           \& \bullet \arrow[ul] \arrow[dd] \\
                                \&                   \&                   \&                   \&\\
\bullet \arrow[uu]                  \&                   \& \bullet \arrow[ll]    \&                   \& \bullet \arrow[ll]
\end{tikzcd}
\task %2
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
\&\&\bullet \arrow[dl] \&\&\\
\bullet \&\bullet \arrow[l] \ar[rr, dotted, dash] \&\&\bullet \arrow[dd] \arrow[ul] \&\\
\&\&\&\&\\
\&\bullet \arrow[uu] \&\bullet \arrow[l] \&\bullet \arrow[l] \& 
\end{tikzcd}
\task %3
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
\&\&\&\bullet \arrow[dll] \&\&\\
\bullet \ar[d] \&\bullet \ar[l] \arrow[rrrr, dotted, dash]  \&\&\&\&\bullet \arrow[ull] \arrow[ddl] \\
\bullet \&\&\&\&\&\\
\&\&\bullet \arrow[uul] \&\&\bullet \arrow[ll] \& 
\end{tikzcd}
\task %4
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
\&\&\bullet \arrow[dll] \&\& \\
\bullet \ar[dd] \arrow[rrrr, dotted, dash] \&\&\&\&\bullet \arrow[ull] \arrow[ddl] \\
\&\&\&\& \\
\bullet \&\bullet \arrow[uul] \&\&\bullet \arrow[ll] \& \bullet \ar[uu]
\end{tikzcd}
\task %5
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
                \&                   \&                                                   \& \bullet           \&\\
\bullet \arrow[dd]  \&                   \& \bullet \arrow[ll] \arrow[rr] \arrow[dd, dotted, dash]    \&                           \& \bullet \arrow[ul] \arrow[dd] \\
                \&                   \&                                                   \&                   \&\\
\bullet \arrow[rr]  \&                   \& \bullet                                           \&                   \& \bullet \arrow[ll]
\end{tikzcd}
\task %6
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
                \&                   \&                               \& \bullet \arrow[ld]    \&\\
\bullet \arrow[dd]  \&                   \& \bullet \arrow[rr, dotted, dash]  \&                           \& \bullet \arrow[ul] \arrow[dd] \\
                \&                   \&                               \&                   \&\\
\bullet \arrow[rr]  \&                   \& \bullet \arrow[uu]                \&                   \& \bullet \arrow[ll]
\end{tikzcd}
\task %7
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
\bullet \arrow[dr]  \&                   \& \bullet \arrow[ll] \arrow[ld, dotted, dash] \arrow[rd]    \&                           \& \bullet \\
                \& \bullet           \&                                                   \& \bullet \arrow[dd] \arrow[ur] \&       \\
                \&                   \&                                                   \&                           \&       \\
                \& \bullet \arrow[uu]    \&                                                   \& \bullet \arrow[ll]            \& 
\end{tikzcd}
\task %8
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
%               \&                           \&                   \&                                                   \&                           \\
\bullet             \& \bullet \arrow[d] \arrow[rr] \arrow[ddrr, dotted, dash]   \& \&\bullet \arrow[dd]   \\
                \& \bullet \arrow[d]                                 \& \&                     \\
\bullet \arrow[uu]  \& \bullet \arrow[l] \arrow[rr]                          \& \& \bullet
\end{tikzcd}
\task %9
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
\bullet \arrow[r] \&\bullet \arrow[dd, dotted, dash] \&\&\bullet \arrow[dd] \\
\&\&\& \\
\bullet \arrow[uu] \&\bullet \arrow[l] \arrow[rr] \&\&\bullet \ar[uull]\\
\&\bullet \ar[u] \&\&
\end{tikzcd}
\task %10
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
\&\&\bullet \arrow[dr] \&\\
\bullet \arrow[r] \&\bullet \arrow[dd, dotted, dash] \&\&\bullet \arrow[dd]    \\
\&\&\&\\
\bullet \ar[r] \&\bullet \arrow[luu] \arrow[rr] \&\&\bullet \arrow[uull]
\end{tikzcd}
\task %11
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
                \&                                                   \& \bullet \arrow[dr]    \&                   \\
\bullet             \& \bullet \arrow[d] \arrow[ddrr, dotted, dash] \arrow[ur]   \&                   \& \bullet \arrow[dd]    \\
                \& \bullet \arrow[d]                                 \&                   \&                   \\
                \& \bullet \arrow[luu] \arrow[rr]                            \&                   \& \bullet   
\end{tikzcd}
\task %12
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
\bullet \arrow[dd] \&\&\bullet \arrow[ll] \arrow[ddr] \&\bullet \\
\&\&\& \\
\bullet \ar[d] \arrow[urur, dotted, dash] \&\&\&\bullet \arrow[dl] \arrow[uu]  \\
\bullet \&\&\bullet \arrow[ull] \& 
\end{tikzcd}
\task %13
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
\bullet \arrow[dd]  \&                   \& \bullet \arrow[ddr, dotted, dash]     \& \bullet \arrow[l]         \\
                \& \bullet \arrow[ur]    \&                               \&                           \\
\bullet \arrow[ur]  \&                   \&                               \& \bullet \arrow[dl] \arrow[uu] \\
                \&                   \& \bullet \arrow[ull]               \& 
\end{tikzcd}
\task %14
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
\bullet \arrow[rr] \&\&\bullet \arrow[ddd, dotted, dash] \&\&\&\bullet \arrow[dddl] \\
\&\&\&\&\& \\
\&\&\&\&\& \\
\bullet \ar[r] \&\bullet \ar[r] \&\bullet \arrow[lluuu] \arrow[rr] \&\&\bullet \arrow[uuull] \& 
\end{tikzcd}
\task %15
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
\bullet     \&\& \bullet \arrow[d] \arrow[rrr]    \&\&                                  \& \bullet \arrow[dddl]  \\
        \&\& \bullet \arrow[d]                \&\&                                  \&                   \\
        \&\& \bullet \arrow[d]                \&\&                                  \&                   \\
        \&\& \bullet \arrow[lluuu] \arrow[rr] \&\& \bullet \arrow[uuull, dotted, dash]  \& 
\end{tikzcd}
\task %16
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
                    \&\&                                                  \& \& \bullet                         \\
\bullet \arrow[drr] \&\& \bullet \arrow[ll] \arrow[drr] \arrow[d, dotted, dash]   \& \& \bullet \arrow[u]               \\
\bullet \arrow[u]       \&\& \bullet                                          \& \& \bullet \arrow[ll] \arrow[u]
\end{tikzcd}
\task %17
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
\bullet \arrow[dd]   \arrow[rrr]    \&                   \&                           \& \bullet \arrow[ddl, dotted, dash] \& \bullet \arrow[dd]    \\
                            \& \bullet \arrow[ul]    \&                           \&                               \&                   \\
\bullet                     \&                   \& \bullet \arrow[ul] \arrow[rr] \&                               \& \bullet \arrow[uul]
\end{tikzcd}
\task %18
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
\&\bullet \arrow[ddl] \&\&\bullet \ar[ll] \\
\&\&\&\\
\bullet \arrow[rr, dotted, dash] \&\& \bullet \ar[uul] \arrow[d] \&\bullet \ar[uu] \ar[l] \arrow[uull, dotted, dash] \\
\bullet \arrow[u] \&\&\bullet \arrow[ll] \&
\end{tikzcd}
\task  %19
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
\bullet \&\bullet \arrow[ddl] \&\&\bullet \arrow[ll] \& \\
\&\&\&\&\\
\bullet \ar[uu] \arrow[rrrr, dotted, dash] \&\&\&\&\bullet \arrow[d] \arrow[uulll]  \\
\bullet \arrow[u] \&\&\&\&\bullet \arrow[llll]
\end{tikzcd}
\task %20
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
\&\&\bullet \arrow[rr] \&\&\bullet \arrow[ddll, dotted, dash] \\
\&\&\&\&\\
\bullet \arrow[rr] \&\&\bullet \arrow[rr] \arrow[uu] \&\&\bullet \arrow[d] \arrow[uu] \\
\bullet \&\&\&\&\bullet \arrow[llll]
\end{tikzcd}
\task %21
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
\&\bullet \arrow[dddl] \&\&\&\bullet \ar[lll] \\
\&\&\&\&\\
\&\&\&\&\\
\bullet \arrow[rr, dotted, dash] \&\&\bullet \arrow[dl] \arrow[uuul] \&\bullet \ar[l] \&\bullet \ar[uuulll, dotted, dash] \ar[uuu] \ar[l] \\
\&\bullet \arrow[ul] \&\&\&
\end{tikzcd}
\task  %22
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
\&\&\bullet \arrow[dddll] \&\&\bullet \arrow[ll] \\
\bullet \&\&\&\&\bullet \ar[dd] \\
\&\&\&\&\\
\bullet \arrow[rrrr, dotted, dash] \ar[uu] \&\&\&\&\bullet \arrow[dll] \arrow[uuull] \\
\&\&\bullet \arrow[ull] \&\& 
\end{tikzcd}
\task %23
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
\&\bullet \arrow[rrr] \&\&\&\bullet \\
\&\&\&\&\\
\&\&\&\&\\
\bullet \arrow[r] \&\bullet \arrow[rr] \ar[uuu] \arrow[uuurrr, dotted, dash] \&\&\bullet \arrow[r] \&\bullet \arrow[d] \arrow[uuu]  \\
\&\&\&\& \bullet 
\end{tikzcd}
\task %24
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
\&\bullet \arrow[dddr] \arrow[dddrr, dotted, dash] \arrow[rr] \&\&\bullet \arrow[ddd] \&\\
\&\&\&\&\\
\&\&\&\&\\
\bullet \arrow[dr] \ar[uuur] \arrow[rr, dotted, dash] \&\&\bullet \arrow[r] \&\bullet \arrow[r] \&\bullet \\
\&\bullet \arrow[ur] \&\&\&
\end{tikzcd}
\task  %25
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny, row sep=tiny]
\&\bullet \arrow[dddr] \arrow[dddrr, dotted, dash] \arrow[rr] \&\&\bullet \arrow[ddd] \&\\
\&\&\&\&\\
\&\&\&\&\\
\bullet \arrow[dr] \ar[uuur] \arrow[rr, dotted, dash] \&\&\bullet \arrow[r] \&\bullet \&\\
\bullet \arrow[u] \&\bullet \arrow[ur] \&\&\&
\end{tikzcd}
\end{tasks}
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that I commented `\usepackage{MnSymbol}`: this package changes the appearance of *all* math symbols, in a way that's not really compatible with the text font you're using. If you just need `\udots` there are other methods for importing the single symbol.